# Remove even, odd classes in ngx-chart with multiple data sets?

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

Is there a configuration within ngx-chart to remove the grey background in the following chart: https://embed.plnkr.co/2eQ9jheOTm8i74vp2EmP?show=preview

Comment: why don't just use css? .ngx-charts .grid-panel.odd rect {
    fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
} etc.

Comment: If you try that css selection, it doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: I tried it, it worked for me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thnk you just need to use css rule

```
.ngx-charts .grid-panel.odd rect {
    fill: none;
}
```

there is no option to disable this one in their api.

Comment: Tried in the demo about and they still appear, it doesn't seem to apply it.

Comment: use `fill: none !important;`

Answer (score 1):

To avoid using `!important`, just define a more specific selector. Also, you might need to use ng-deep to get over angular view encapsulation, but keep in mind that it is marked as something which will eventualy be deprecated.

```
::ng-deep
.ngx-charts g .grid-panel.odd rect {
  fill: none;
}
```